# MySQL does not give me a temporary password

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have often tried to install *MySQL* but I do not get a temporary password in the log. And when I try to run `mysql_secure_installtion` the password will be also not set. Why?

I get this [error.log](https://pastebin.com/gQvZbn4Z).

Comment: Did you see this line in the log `root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.`

Comment: @RiggsFolly the 6'th line of the linked error.log contains this line.

Comment: I assume you spelt `mysql_secure_installation` correctly when you used is for real?